# Convert log10 number that is a string into float pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe here.

```
Year    Month   Day Extent
1   1978    10  26  10.231
2   1978    10  28  10.420
3   1978    10  30  10.557
4   1978    11  1   10.670
5   1978    11  3   10.777
```

The type for my columns are:

```
Year      object
Month     object
Day       object
Extent    object
dtype: object
```

I would like to change the values into a float.

Expected output (with Extent as an float, not a str):

```
 Year   Month   Day Extent
    1   1978    10  26  10.231
    2   1978    10  28  10.420
    3   1978    10  30  10.557
    4   1978    11  1   10.670
    5   1978    11  3   10.777
```

EDIT: I was confused on the meaning of float and integer. Sorry. Edited my post above to reflect.

Comment: The question is unclear: what integer value _do_ you want `"10.231"` to be converted to? (And what do you mean by the values being "in log10"?)

Comment: I edited the post to better reflect the issue.

Comment: do you need it to be an integer or a float? your wording is still confusing, what do you want your output to be?

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.floor`:

```
ice_data['Extent'] = np.floor(ice_data.Extent).astype(int)
```

Or a simple `//1`:

```
ice_data['Extent'] = (ice_data.Extent//1).astype(int)
```

---

**Update**: For string type:

```
ice_data['Extent'] = ice_data.Extent.str.extract('^(\d+)')[0].astype(int)
```

Comment: This does not work since the type of Extent when loaded in is a str.

Comment: Replace `ice_data.Extent` with `ice_data.Extent.astype(float)`.

Comment: As stated in my post though, the float removes the extra precision that I need, so this is not a viable option.

Comment: I got this error when I tried your updated code, ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @EliTurasky But you are making integers out of the float, I'm not sure whether precision is a problem. Anyhow, see update.

Comment: @EliTurasky your data contains `nan` values. Usually you would get a float column. Try `astype('Int64')` instead of `astype(int)`. If that fails, you probably need to upgrade your pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

ice_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Year    Month   Day Extent
1   1978    10  26  10.231
2   1978    10  28  10.420
3   1978    10  30  10.557
4   1978    11  1   10.670
5   1978    11  3   10.777"""), sep='\s+')
ice_data['Extent'] = ice_data['Extent'].astype(int)
print(ice_data)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Month  Day  Extent
1  1978     10   26      10
2  1978     10   28      10
3  1978     10   30      10
4  1978     11    1      10
5  1978     11    3      10
```

Comment: Hi @EliTurasky. What's the expected output?

Comment: @EliTurasky Integer doesn't have a decimal point. What are you looking for?